# html get div tag in many levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got `class required` on `div tag`, and I want to remove it `change function` of `text field`, but I can't get to that div level, please help me to reach `this.parent.parent.closest('div')`

```
<div class='required'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='123' onchange(removeRequired(this, this.parent.parent.closest('div')))/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function removeRequired(elm1, elm2){
        if ($(elm1).val()) {
            $(elm2).removeClass('required');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What you have there is invalid HTML.

Comment: Your `onchange` attribute is invalid HTML so will not work anyway.

Comment: `onchange="removeRequired(...)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want is to add/remove the required class based on whether the input is empty or not.

```
$('.required').on('change', 'input', function(event) {
   // add or remove required class
   $(event.delegateTarget)
       .toggleClass('required', this.value.length === 0);
});
```

It will work with the following HTML:

```
<div class='required'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='123'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It sets up event delegation on the outermost `<div>` elements and then sets or removes the `required` class based on the input value.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/lefirete/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to mess up with javascript and jquery. You can bind the change event with jquery like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='text'] ").change(function () {
        $(this).closest(".required").removeClass("required");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("input[type=text]").closest('div.required').removeClass("required");
```

onchange function be

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function(){
  $(this).closest("div.required").removeClass("required");
});
```

or

```
  $("input[type='text']").change(function(){
      $(this).parents("div.required").removeClass("required");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not easily working with id?

```
<div id="input-wrapper" class='required'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type='text' value='123' onchange="removeRequired(this, $('#input-wrapper'))"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function removeRequired(elm1, elm2){
        if ($(elm1).val()) {
            $(elm2).removeClass('required');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you want to reach the div class='required' with parent, you need 3 levels! Althougth the use of closest() is by far a better answer.

You can try:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<div class='required'>
    <div>
        <div>
              <input type='text' value='123' onchange="removeRequired.call(this)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function removeRequired(){
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('required');
    }
</script>
```